# uploading an image from flash using php more specifically HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Tags: php, flash, upload, directory

I currently have it working so it displays a dialogue box to save the image on your computer:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{

// get bytearray
$jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

// add headers for download dialog-box
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
    echo $jpg;
}
```

just wondered if there is any way to put the file straight into a directory/file without the need of a dialogue box?

like an uploader?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

Comment: is there any way of uploading at all using http raw post data?

Comment: no. using http raw post data has nothing to do with download. you have messed up download and upload. you're using HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA to send a file from user to server (upload) and echo to send it back (download). But it doesn't matter as you cannot save a file on the user's computer without user permission anyway. Period.

Answer (score 0):

Just Read the content of the page and save in a file using fopen , fwrite e.t.c.

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){

    // get bytearray
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    // add headers for download dialog-box
 ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
       echo $jpg;
  $image=ob_get_clean();
   //and here write it into file      
  }
```

OR following is my code you can remove unneccessary things that are not useful for you

```
 if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] ))     {
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
$filename=$_GET['name'];
$fullFilePath='files/'.$filename;
$handle=fopen($fullFilePath,"w");
fwrite($handle,$im);
fclose($handle);
$returnVars = array();
$returnVars['write'] = "yes";
$returnString = http_build_query($returnVars);
//send variables back to Flash
echo $returnString;
  }
```